# Django load model database values using ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am working on a side project using django framework. I need to direct the page to another website when a user clicks a `<div>` area without refreshing the page. I searched around and found ajax should be my option. I followed some questions on stackoverflow but it didn't work. What I want to do is: the user clicks the div region,

```
<div onclick=window.open("{{link}}");>
```

link is a variable from django/views; then without refreshing the page, if the user clicks the page again, it will direct to another link. The link is generated from the database and is randomly selected after each click.

My template using jQuery/ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myDiv").on("click",function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
                success:function(){
                    window.open({{link}});
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    modellinks=model_link.objects.values_list('links',flat=True)

    link=random.choice(modellinks)


    return render(request,'myapp/index.html',{'link':link})
```

adding problems...
    The problem is that when I used the above template and views.py, by        clicking the div area, it doesn't link to any website. But without using ajax, I can make the div area link to other website using div onclick event.
I think I may have something wrong with the above ajax in the template or     views.py when using ajax.

Did I write my template right? How do I modify views.py to connect views.py and ajax?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I used the above template and views.py, by clicking the div area, it doesn't link to any website.  But without using ajax, I can make the div area link to other website using <div onclick=window.open({{link}})>. I think I may have something wrong with the above ajax in the template or views.py when using ajax.

Comment: The reason I want to use Ajax is that I want to update the {{link}} values automatically once onclick event happen in the div area without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: You did not get the data from your views in your ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to try something along these lines:

**views.py:**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):
    modellinks = model_link.objects.values_list('links', flat=True)
    link = random.choice(modellinks)

    data = {
       'link': link
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myDiv").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                window.open(data.link)
            },
            error: function (rs, e) {
                alert('Sorry, try again.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**html:**

```
<button id="myDiv" type=submit>Open Link</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the codes.  But when I tried them, the IE just display {"link": "http://www.bing.com"} instead of the button (open link). Shouldn't the views.py should have myapp/index.html in addtion to JsonResponse? otherwise, how the system know which template should I use.

Comment: @Wanlie Ajax calls work anywhere you put the Javascript. You identify them by changing the tags (i.e. `#myDiv`). Are you putting the JS in your template, or in your base template?

Comment: I put ajax in the index.html. using the html you provided, I even can't get the button. IE just diplay the text with the curly{"link":"website" }. Views.py is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Actually I need to set another view method to return the index.html to make ajax work.